# SQL Ranking columns and pulling in top 3

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables in Snowflake - one with color data and one with ranks for each color :

| Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 | Type5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | white | yellow | red | white |
| yellow | white | yellow | white | yellow |

| color | rank |
| --- | --- |
| red | 1 |
| white | 2 |
| yellow | 3 |

How can I pull in top 3 colors with highest ranks in the same row? (rank 1 is the highest and if there are ties, you can pull in any of the ties). Actual data is much larger so hoping to find a solution that avoids manual case statements.

Desired result is the following:

| Highest | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | red | white |
| white | white | yellow |

Answer (score 1):

if we turn you data into tables/CTE's:

```
with types(id, c1, c2) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'r', 'y' ),
        (2, 'w', 'w' ),
        (3, 'y', 'y' ),
        (4, 'r', 'w' ),
        (5, 'w', 'y' )
), ranks (c, r) as (
    select * from values
        ('r', 1),
        ('w', 2),
        ('y', 3)
)
```

then a double join with can be used to check the rank value and thus rank order:

```
select
    t.c1
    ,t.c2
    ,r1.r + r2.r as rank_val
    ,row_number() over (order by (r1.r + r2.r) ) as rank_order
from types as t
join ranks as r1
    on t.c1 = r1.c
join ranks as r2
    on t.c2 = r2.c
```

[image]

which means we can then use a qualify to filter:

```
select
    t.c1
    ,t.c2
from types as t
join ranks as r1
    on t.c1 = r1.c
join ranks as r2
    on t.c2 = r2.c
qualify row_number() over (order by (r1.r + r2.r) ) <= 3;
```

[image]

Or we can just use a [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode) (which is compact version of a CASE, which you noted you did not want to use, your choice, just more options)

```
select
    t.c1
    ,t.c2
    ,decode(t.c1, 'r', 1, 'w', 2, 'y', 3) + decode(t.c2, 'r', 1, 'w', 2, 'y', 3) as rank_val
from types as t
order by rank_val
```

[image]

thus qualify on that instead:

```
with types(id, c1, c2) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'r', 'y' ),
        (2, 'w', 'w' ),
        (3, 'y', 'y' ),
        (4, 'r', 'w' ),
        (5, 'w', 'y' )
)
select
    t.c1
    ,t.c2
from types as t
qualify row_number() over (order by decode(t.c1, 'r', 1, 'w', 2, 'y', 3) + decode(t.c2, 'r', 1, 'w', 2, 'y', 3) ) <= 3
;
```

[image]

noting this is an unstable sort, and for data sets, you will get random behavior on the margin out of this, thus some form of secondary+ sorts should be added, to make the data stable.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in the snowflake but Oracle.
You can take the idea from this Oracle query:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN NEW_RANK = 1 THEN COLOR END) AS HIGHEST,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NEW_RANK = 2 THEN COLOR END) AS SECOND,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NEW_RANK = 3 THEN COLOR END) AS THIRD
FROM
    (SELECT ID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RNK) AS NEW_RANK, 
            COLOR 
       FROM
        (SELECT T.ID, 
                CASE WHEN L.LVL =1 THEN R1.RANK
                     WHEN L.LVL =2 THEN R2.RANK
                     WHEN L.LVL =3 THEN R3.RANK
                     WHEN L.LVL =4 THEN R4.RANK
                     WHEN L.LVL =5 THEN R5.RANK 
                END AS RNK,
                CASE WHEN L.LVL =1 THEN R1.COLOR
                     WHEN L.LVL =2 THEN R2.COLOR
                     WHEN L.LVL =3 THEN R3.COLOR
                     WHEN L.LVL =4 THEN R4.COLOR
                     WHEN L.LVL =5 THEN R5.COLOR 
                END AS COLOR
           FROM TYPES T
            JOIN RANKS R1 ON R1.COLOR = T.TYPE1
            JOIN RANKS R2 ON R2.COLOR = T.TYPE2
            JOIN RANKS R3 ON R3.COLOR = T.TYPE3
            JOIN RANKS R4 ON R4.COLOR = T.TYPE4
            JOIN RANKS R5 ON R5.COLOR = T.TYPE5
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL LVL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5) L
        )
    )
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

I am getting the correct result with sample data.

[Result with Oracle DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjiYC.png)