# SQL rank and reorder columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables in Snowflake - one with color data and one with ranks for each color:

**Color** table:

| Index | color1 | color2 | color3 | color4 | color5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | orange | red | blue | violet |
| 2 | indigo | yellow | blue | yellow | violet |

**Rank** table:

| Color | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Yellow | 3 |
| Green | 4 |
| Blue | 5 |
| Indigo | 6 |
| Orange | 7 |
| Violet | 8 |

I'd like to use the two tables above to rank each colors in each row and show top 3 colors in the resulting table. So resulting table will have red, red, and orange for index 1 and yellow, yellow, and blue for index 2.

| Index | Rank1 | Rank2 | Rank3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | red | orange |
| 2 | yellow | yellow | blue |

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far as a [mre]? Are [JavaScript stored procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedure/stored-procedures-javascript) available for use in your environment?

Comment: I'm lost on how to approach this. I was thinking I could possibly put the colors in an array with ranks, order them, and get the top 3 but not sure how I can approach this in snowflake sql.  I don't think javascript is available to use in snowflake.

Comment: JavaScript is certainly available in Snowflake itself (see the Snowflake KB article I linked, among many others linked therein), but the acceptability of its use is something that may be dependent on your org's policies. A better way to ask might be: do you have any restrictions disallowing the use of JavaScript-based stored procedures or UDFs in your organization's Snowflake tenant? At first pass, it seems it'd be significantly easier to accomplish this using the JavaScript features of the platform than without.

Comment: No, there is no restrictions on using javascript-based stored procedures.

Comment: @CLV You should be able to do this with a PIVOT, then join to "Rank" table. Then filter on rank(), the window function not table name, <= 3. Then UNPIVOT.

Comment: Thank you for your response - @Error_2646. Can you elaborate on your thought process on each step? Are you using the Pivot to expand multiple colors in each index before joining rank? What is 'the window function not table name'?

Comment: I am surprised you did improve you last question, verse just asking the same question a second time (albeit, better asked this time) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609698/sql-ranking-columns-and-pulling-in-top-3

Comment: As @SimeonPilgrim identified, this is a duplicate of your previous question. Please don't ask duplicative questions - edit your old ones with more details if the answers provided there don't meet your needs. Voting to close as duplicate of [SQL Ranking columns and pulling in top 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609698/sql-ranking-columns-and-pulling-in-top-3)

Answer (score 2):

So using the CTE for the DATA, and encoding the ranking via [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode) (this step could be a TABLE/CTE and a join could be used). We [UNPIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot) the five color columns and then assign the color rank, and then rank the ranks with [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number), we then filter out the position above 3 and then use PIVOT to roll these back into wide columns, and use MAX to keep the non-null values.

```
with data(idx, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) as (
    select *
    from values
     (1, 'red', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'violet'),
     (2, 'indigo', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'violet')
), unpivoted as (
    select 
        *
        ,decode(color, 'red', 1, 
            'orange', 2,
            'yellow', 3,
            'green',4,
            'blue', 5,
            'indigo', 6,
            'orange', 7,
            'violet', 8) as rank
        ,row_number() over (partition by idx order by rank) as position
    from data
    UNPIVOT(color FOR col IN (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))
    qualify position <= 3
)
select 
    idx
    ,max("1") as color1
    ,max("2") as color2
    ,max("3") as color3
from unpivoted
PIVOT(MAX(color) FOR position IN (1,2,3))
      AS p
group by 1
order by 1;
```

[image]

### MIN_BY:

The [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot) can be swapped for [MIN_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by) like so:

```
with data(idx, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) as (
    select *
    from values
     (1, 'red', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'violet'),
     (2, 'indigo', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'violet')
), unpivoted as (
    select 
        *
        ,decode(color, 'red', 1, 
            'orange', 2,
            'yellow', 3,
            'green',4,
            'blue', 5,
            'indigo', 6,
            'orange', 7,
            'violet', 8) as rank
        ,row_number() over (partition by idx order by rank) as position
    from data
    UNPIVOT(color FOR col IN (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))
    qualify position <= 3
)
select idx, min_by(color, position, 3) as min3
from unpivoted
group by 1;
```

[image]

at which point, you could pull the three values out in another layer:

```
with data(idx, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) as (
    select *
    from values
     (1, 'red', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'violet'),
     (2, 'indigo', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'violet')
), unpivoted as (
    select 
        *
        ,decode(color, 'red', 1, 
            'orange', 2,
            'yellow', 3,
            'green',4,
            'blue', 5,
            'indigo', 6,
            'orange', 7,
            'violet', 8) as rank
        ,row_number() over (partition by idx order by rank) as position
    from data
    UNPIVOT(color FOR col IN (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))
), arrayed as (
    select idx, min_by(color, position, 3) as min3
    from unpivoted
    group by 1
)
select 
    idx, 
    min3[0]::text as c1, 
    min3[1]::text as c2, 
    min3[2]::text as c3
from arrayed;
```

[image]

### using tables:

```
create table data as 
    select *
    from values
     (1, 'red', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'violet'),
     (2, 'indigo', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'violet')
     t(idx, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5);

create table ranks as 
    select *
    from values
    ('red', 1),
    ('orange', 2),
    ('yellow', 3),
    ('green', 4),
    ('blue', 5),
    ('indigo', 6),
    ('orange', 7),
    ('violet', 8)  
    t(color, rank);
```

we can use a natural join like so:

```
with pos_and_rank as (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by idx order by rank) as position
    from (
        select idx, color
        from data
            UNPIVOT(color FOR col IN (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))
    )
    natural join ranks

), arrayed as (
    select idx, min_by(color, position, 3) as min3
    from pos_and_rank
    group by 1
)
select 
    idx, 
    min3[0]::text as c1, 
    min3[1]::text as c2, 
    min3[2]::text as c3
from arrayed
order by idx;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: this is pretty ugly, but it should get the job done.**

Borrowing a bit from @Error_2646's idea in [the comments on the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77641560/sql-rank-and-reorder-columns?noredirect=1#comment136879153_77641560), you could `UNPIVOT` your existing data structure, `JOIN` to the `Rank` information, then re-cobble the data into your prescribed format. The actual practicality of this will likely depend on the scale of the data on which you intend to apply this to, and hasn't been tested on any meaningfully large dataset.

(I've elected not to `PIVOT` the data back in and instead have manually assembled it using a few subqueries, since `PIVOT`'s support for, and performance on, textual data is generally quite suboptimal.)

```
WITH unpivoted_data AS (
  SELECT 
    [Index], 
    Color.Color, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY [Index] 
      ORDER BY 
        Rank.Rank
    ) AS PartitionRank 
  FROM 
    Color UNPIVOT (
      Color FOR Colors IN (
        color1, color2, color3, color4, color5
      )
    ) AS Color 
    JOIN Rank ON LOWER(Rank.Color) = Color.Color
) 
SELECT 
  [Index], 
  (
    SELECT 
      Color 
    FROM 
      unpivoted_data 
    WHERE 
      unpivoted_data.[Index] = ranked_colors.[Index] 
      AND unpivoted_data.[PartitionRank] = 1
  ) AS Rank1, 
  (
    SELECT 
      Color 
    FROM 
      unpivoted_data 
    WHERE 
      unpivoted_data.[Index] = ranked_colors.[Index] 
      AND unpivoted_data.[PartitionRank] = 2
  ) AS Rank2, 
  (
    SELECT 
      Color 
    FROM 
      unpivoted_data 
    WHERE 
      unpivoted_data.[Index] = ranked_colors.[Index] 
      AND unpivoted_data.[PartitionRank] = 3
  ) AS Rank3 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT [Index] 
    FROM 
      unpivoted_data
  ) ranked_colors 
ORDER BY 
  [Index] ASC
```

Result:

| Index | Rank1 | Rank2 | Rank3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | red | orange |
| 2 | yellow | yellow | blue |

Comment: Thank you for your response! What is the 'pivoted_data' condition above? Also, could you possibly provide a version using pivot as well?

Comment: @CLV Apologies - `pivoted_data` was a holdover from me just trying to test this with dumb variable names - I've updated it to be `ranked_colors` instead. I believe the other answer can get you to where you need to be with `PIVOT`.